# Refer to an object inside an $.getJSON() with append

Tags: jquery, json

i try to get a json list and append it

```
$.getJSON("url",
        function(data){
        $('#tbl').append("<li id="listitem">asd</li>);
        });
```

It works but i cant access the li object with

```
$("#listitem").hover( alert("Hover"); );
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin. It should help in these case. Try something like this:

```
$('#tbl').append("<li id="listitem">asd</li>).livequery( 'hover', doMagic() );
```

Comment: thanks livequery solved it :-)

$('a') 
    .livequery('click', function(event) { 
        alert('clicked'); 
        return false; 
    });

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$("#listitem").hover( function() {alert("Hover");} );
```

`hover` expects an anonymous function or a callback.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `.on()` method. More information can be [found here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('#container').on('hover', '#listitem', function(){
     alert("Hover"); 
});
```

Note: #container should be a parent element that does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't access the `li` element, because you are mixing `"` in different scopes, so the resulting string is not valid.

`$('#tbl').append("<li id="listitem">asd</li>);`

The inner `"` delimiters should be escaped like `\"`

`$('#tbl').append("<li id=\"listitem\">asd</li>);`